# HTML to Excel changes the code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

In asp.net (vb), I am trying to write the HTML output that I can have a user open up a report in Excel.  It's writing my file fine, but when Excel opens the file it is changing the HTML code.  The part that it really changes are formulas!

For instance, I am writing out the following (part of the file):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Trial</td><td x:num x:fmla="=SUM(A2:A10)">0</td>
</tr>
</tr></table>
```

If I open the file in Excel, the cell has a formula of SUM(A13:A21).

Is there something I can do to prevent Excel from changing this when it opens?  I want it to have exactly what I write, but it is changing A LOT!

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: `x:fmla="=SUM($A$2:$A$10)"`

Comment: Changes that to SUM($A$13:$A$21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives me the expected outcome:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Trial</td><td x:num x:fmla="=SUM($A$2:$A$10)">0</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Even without the $ the formula remains as-written: no adjustment.
Excel 2013/Win7

Comment: I'm doing something wrong in my header info then.  This worked perfect for me as well.  Thanks for heading me in the right direction and clearing my eyes!

Comment: Check there's no client-side caching going on - that can lead to odd results.

Answer (score 0):

Tim headed me in the right direction, so thanks.

I'm posting what I found was my idiotic error, just to answer the question.  No one is going to do what I did, but here it is.

I was doing a "table" tag for everything when I wrote my program, so my HTML looked like this:

```
<table><tr>
<tr>
<td x:num>11</td>
<td x:num>12</td>
<td x:num>13</td>
<td x:num>14</td>
</tr></table>

<table> <tr>
<td x:num>21</td>
<td x:num>22</td>
<td x:num>23</td>
<td x:num>24</td>
</tr></table>

<table> <tr>
<td x:num>31</td>
<td x:num>32</td>
<td x:num>33</td>
<td x:num>34</td>
</tr></table>


<tr>
<td>Total Weight</td>
<td></td>
<td x:num x:fmla="=SUM(D4:D10)">0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Obviously, that was changing everything.  Changed it to one "table" at the top and "/table" at the end to fix it all.

Thanks for the help!

Ed